# Simple PDO update is not working

Tags: php, pdo

The problem is on :soundid if I type manually soundid='soundidfromPOST' received from POST, the row is updated, but with soundid=:soundid ... nothing. Why?

PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION and error_reporting enabled.

```
public function save($args) {
    $userid = Controller::getUserConnection();
    if ($userid) {
        $soundid = $_POST['soundid'];
        $track_title = $_POST['track_title'];
        $track_artist = $_POST['track_artist'];
        $track_album = $_POST['track_album'];
        $track_genre = $_POST['track_genre'];
        $track_description = $_POST['track_description'];
        $played = 1;
        $statement = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE sounds SET title=:track_title, artist=:track_artist, album=:track_album, genre_id=:track_genre, description=:track_description, played=:played WHERE soundid=:soundid AND userid=:userid AND ip=:ip");
        $statement->bindParam(':soundid',$soundid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':userid',$userid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindParam(':track_title',$track_title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':track_artist',$track_artist,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':track_album',$track_album,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':track_genre',$track_genre,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->bindParam(':track_description',$track_description,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':ip',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(':played',$played,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->execute();
        echo 'saved!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is soundid a number? You're binding it as a string. You can also check `var_dump($statement->ErrorInfo())` and `var_dump($this->_db->ErrorInfo())` to see what the error from the database is.

Comment: Isn't the post array outside the function? Try to pass the post vars as params?

Comment: @RoyalBg - $_POST is automatically available as a global.

Comment: @RoyalBg I tried the post vars as params and nothing... and nothing

Comment: @andrewsi soundid is a string.

Comment: @RoyalBg `[$_POST] is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions or methods.` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: @andrewsi the both var_dump: array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL } array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }

Comment: try - `$statement->bindParam(':soundid',$soundid,PDO::PARAM_INT);`?

Comment: @MGE - Hmmmm. That means that there were no errors encounterd - where in the code did you add the var_dump lines?

Comment: @Sean the same problem. soundid is a string

Comment: @andrewsi after execute

Comment: @MGE - That's odd. All I can think then is that the update is running, but no rows are being updated because it's not meeting the WHERE part of the update clause. Are you sure that there are entries in your database that meet all three criteria, especially the IP one?

Comment: echo $soundid; //output -> aabb4c
WHERE soundid='aabb4c' ... row updated :/

Comment: @andrewsi yes, if I code WHERE soundid='aabb4c' directly, the row is updated

Comment: @MGE - then I'm stumped. Does it also work if you try adding it directly into the string, as 'soundid=' . $_POST['soundid'] . ' AND....' ?

Comment: @MGE, first make sure there is no spaces or other special characters in the input string (use statement's debugDumpParams() method). Also make sure you check that return value of execute() is true and that rowCount() returns greater than zero.

Comment: debugDumpsParams: http://pastebin.com/PFkZenV8

Comment: and rowCount returns 0

Comment: @MGE what does `var_dump($soundid)` give ?

Comment: string(9) " abd1ffb" WTF? blank space? when i show echo, the blank dessapear...

Comment: @MGE - in that pastebin, soundid's param_type is given as 1, while ip's param_type is 2. 2 is String, and 1 is an integer. It looks like it's not being set properly to a String, for some reason.

Comment: @MGE, If rowCount() returns 0, where part does not match with the data in table. debugDumpParams() should output values as well, try executing it right before/after the execute() call.

Comment: @MGE ok, try `$soundid = trim($_POST['soundid']);`

Comment: You could also try using bindValue() instead of bindParam(). There's something weird going on with the parameter type (@andrewsi noted this).

Comment: Solved with trim(); I can't understand... why the spaces in POST.. Thanks everybody!

Comment: lol, always `var_duuuuuuuump` :p

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following to make it cleaner and because you don't need to bind everything explicitly (please note I didn't use all your variables):

Assign all your post data that you want to use in the query to an array:

```
$data = array(
   'userid' => $userid,
   'sounddid' => $_POST['soundid'],
   'track_title' => $_POST['track_title'],
   'track_artist' => $_POST['track_title'],
   'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
);
```

Write you query:

```
$sth = $this->_db->prepare("
    UPDATE sounds SET 
    title = :track_title, 
    artist = :track_artist
    WHERE soundid = :soundid 
    AND userid = :userid 
    AND ip = :ip
");
```

Pass in your data array to be executed:

```
$result = $sth->execute($data);
```

Comment: I suppose that this method could be combined with bindParam, right?